# Can I avoid explicitly calling RaisePropertyChanged for dependent properties?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have

```
    public override bool RelatedProperty
    {
        get { return this.SomeProperty > 0; }
    }

    public int SomeProperty
    {
        get { return this.someProperty; }
        protected set
        {
            this.Set<int>(ref this.someProperty, value);
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(this.RelatedProperty));
        }
    }
```

where `RelatedProperty` is obviously dependent on `SomeProperty`.

Is there a better way to update the binding, than invoking `RaisePropertyChanged` for `RelatedProperty`, from the setter of `SomeProperty`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better way to update the binding, than invoking RaisePropertyChanged for RelatedProperty, from the setter of SomeProperty?

No. At least not using MvvmLight and the imperative approach of implementing properties.

If you were using a reactive UI framework such as [ReactiveUI](http://reactiveui.net/) you would handle property changes in a functional way:

```
public class ReactiveViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public ReactiveViewModel()
    {
        this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.SomeProperty).Select(_ => SomeProperty > 0)
            .ToProperty(this, x => x.RelatedProperty, out _relatedProperty);
    }

    private int _someProperty;
    public int SomeProperty
    {
        get { return _someProperty; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _someProperty, value); }
    }

    private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool> _relatedProperty;
    public bool RelatedProperty
    {
        get { return _relatedProperty.Value; }
    }
}
```

You can read more about this in the docs for ReactiveUI and on the creator Paul Betts' blog if you are interested:

https://docs.reactiveui.net/en/fundamentals/functional-reactive-programming.html
http://log.paulbetts.org/creating-viewmodels-with-reactiveobject/